# Get values from Moodle array

Tags: php, moodle

I am new to Moodle I have an array `$user`. I var_dump() the object and I get like this:

```
 var_dump($user);

Result
-------

array (size=1)
  6 => 
    object(stdClass)[938]
      public 'id' => string '6' (length=1)
      public 'userid' => string '5' (length=1)
      public 'status' => string '1' (length=1)
```

I need to get the values `id, userid, status`. How can I extract that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want a single user from the array, then you can write:

```
$firstuser = reset($user);
echo $firstuser->id;
echo $firstuser->status;
```

If there are several users in the array, you can loop through them with:

```
foreach ($user as $singleuser) {
    echo $singleuser->id;
    echo $singleuser->status;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write:-

```
$id = $user->id;
$user_id = $user->userid;
$status = $user->status;
```

Comment: I got the solution: $user = array_values($user);
 echo $user[0]->id;